# Is there any way to reuse an arraylist in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists . I want just reuse the second arraylist (temporaryArrayList). Please notice my code . Hope you of course will understand what i want to make you know.

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrayListContainer = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> temporaryArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    temporaryArrayList.add("I");
    temporaryArrayList.add("you");
    temporaryArrayList.add("he");
    temporaryArrayList.add("she");
    temporaryArrayList.add("we");

    arrayListContainer.add(temporaryArrayList);

    temporaryArrayList.clear();

    temporaryArrayList.add("Rahim");
    temporaryArrayList.add("jon");
    temporaryArrayList.add("don");
    temporaryArrayList.add("shaila");

    arrayListContainer.add(temporaryArrayList);
    temporaryArrayList.clear();


    System.out.println(arrayListContainer.size());
```

The code is giving expected size of arrayListContainer but does not give expected result for

```
System.out.println(arrayListContainer.get(0).get(0));
```

How can I achieve this. Any kind of reply or suggestion will be accepted thankfully.

Comment: What are you expecting `System.out.println(arrayListContainer.get(0).get(0));` to give you?

Comment: Why do you want to re-use the `temporaryArrayList`? As the answers point out, you are going to have to make a copy of it anyway. So there are not any savings, only more confusion.

Comment: I need an arraylist of type arraylist for my project  ..

Comment: See my answer - extract the creation of the temporary ArrayList to a method and call the method to create each ArrayList that you are adding to arrayListContainer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding the same object and deleting it as well.
In order to add *different* temp-lists to `arrayListContainer` you should create a copy:

change the lines that do:

```
arrayListContainer.add(temporaryArrayList);
```

to:

```
ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<>(temporaryArrayList)
arrayListContainer.add(copy);
```

Another option, as Thilo suggests in a comment below, would be to create a new `temporaryArrayList` every time, this way you'll ensure adding *different* temp lists to `arrayListContainer` as well.

Comment: ... or just don't reuse the temporaryArrayList in the first place. Much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a clone of the ArrayList when you add it, otherwise when you delete the contents you are erasing the contents of the actual list you just added.  Cloning it will add a *copy* of the ArrayList instead of the original.

EDIT:  Actually - based on Thilo's comment on the other answer - a better solution would be to extract the temporary ArrayList code to a method and call it:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrayListContainer = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] a = {"I","you","he"};
    arrayListContainer.add(createArrayList(a));
    String[] b = {"Bob","Rahim","Betty"};
    arrayListContainer.add(createArrayList(b));

    System.out.println(arrayListContainer.size());
    System.out.println(arrayListContainer.get(0).get(0));
 }

 private static ArrayList<String> createArrayList(String[] arr) {
     ArrayList<String> temporaryArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
     for(String str : arr) {
         temporaryArrayList.add(str);
     }
     return temporaryArrayList;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Other Answers are correct. You *are* reusing your second `ArrayList`, just not in the fashion you intended.

You need to understand (a) references to objects, and (b) ArrayList is an object that is a container of references to other objects.

Let's look at the state during the execution of your code.

First instantiate an `ArrayList` with the default of ten slots. Will hold references to other `ArrayList` instances that hold references to `String` objects.

```
ArrayList< ArrayList< String > > arrayListContainer = new ArrayList<>();
```

[image]

```
ArrayList< String > temporaryArrayList = new ArrayList<>() ;
```

[image]

Instantiate `String` objects, adding a reference to each in a slot in our second list. Remember the list contains a *reference* to the `String` object, not the object itself.

```
temporaryArrayList.add( "I" ) ;
temporaryArrayList.add( "you" ) ;
temporaryArrayList.add( "he" ) ;
temporaryArrayList.add( "she" ) ;
temporaryArrayList.add( "we" ) ;
```

[image]

Add a reference to the second list to the first slot of the first list.

```
arrayListContainer.add(temporaryArrayList) ;
```

[image]

Remove all the references to the `String` objects with pronouns by calling `clear()`. Those `String` objects actually exist in memory for a while, becoming candidates for garbage collection since they are not referenced by any other objects. So we show them as gone in this diagram, but actually they may be floating around in memory for a while longer.

```
temporaryArrayList.clear() ;
```

[image]

Instantiate some new `String` objects. Put a reference to each in the slots of our second list.

```
temporaryArrayList.add( "Rahim" ) ;
temporaryArrayList.add( "jon" ) ;
temporaryArrayList.add( "don" ) ;
temporaryArrayList.add( "shaila" ) ;
```

[image]

Here is where your misunderstanding appears. You apparently wanted to keep the pronouns and add some proper names alongside them. But the first list does not hold references to `String` objects, it holds a reference to an `ArrayList` of `String` objects. So we end up two references to the same `ArrayList` object containing references to proper name strings. The old  pronoun strings may or may not be still floating around in memory, but we can no longer reach them so we think of them as gone.

```
arrayListContainer.add( temporaryArrayList ) ;
```

[image]

Next you clear the one-and-only list of strings. So now the first `ArrayList` hold two references to the same now-empty second `ArrayList`.

```
temporaryArrayList.clear() ;
```

[image]

You end up with one list of two elements where each element is pointing to the same empty "temp" list.

If you wanted to accumulate the strings in the first list, redefine that first list as an `ArrayList` of `String` rather than of `ArrayList<String>`. So, instead of this:

```
ArrayList< ArrayList< String > > arrayListContainer = new ArrayList<>() ;
ArrayList< String > temporaryArrayList = new ArrayList<>() ;
…
arrayListContainer.add( temporaryArrayList ) ;
```

…this, changing `add` to `addAll`:

```
ArrayList< String > arrayListContainer = new ArrayList<>() ;
ArrayList< String > temporaryArrayList = new ArrayList<>() ;
…
arrayListContainer.addAll( temporaryArrayList ) ;  // Call `addAll` to add the elements of one collection to another collection.
```

---

Tip: Use interfaces where possible.

Generally best to specify more generic interfaces rather than concrete classes, so you can more easily switch out concrete classes; so you could use `List`: `List< List<String> >`.

```
List<List<String>> listContainer = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrayListContainer = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> temporaryArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    temporaryArrayList.add("I");
    temporaryArrayList.add("you");
    temporaryArrayList.add("he");
    temporaryArrayList.add("she");
    temporaryArrayList.add("we");

    arrayListContainer.add(new ArrayList<>(temporaryArrayList));

   temporaryArrayList.clear();

    temporaryArrayList.add("Rahim");
    temporaryArrayList.add("jon");
    temporaryArrayList.add("don");
    temporaryArrayList.add("shaila");

    arrayListContainer.add(new ArrayList<>(temporaryArrayList));
    temporaryArrayList.clear();


    System.out.println(arrayListContainer.get(0).get(0));
```

This is just another natural way of cloning the object :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't reuse it in the way you want.  Your `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` contains *references* to objects (in this case, references to `ArrayList<String>`).  If you say

```
arrayListContainer.add(temporaryArrayList);
```

and later,

```
arrayListContainer.add(temporaryArrayList);
```

without assigning a new value to `temporaryArrayList` in between, your `arrayListContainer` will have two references to the same object.  `temporaryArrayList` is a reference to an object, and it doesn't change even if the contents of the object change (unless you reassign a whole new object to it).

You'll need to create a new object.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you don't need an array list of array list, just make it an array list of string array:

```
ArrayList<String[]> arrayContainer = new ArrayList<>();
```

When done adding the strings, call:

```
arrayContainer.add(temporaryArrayList.toArray(new String[temporaryArrayList.size()]));
```

That way you can safely reuse the temp array list.